# Do I need PCR test to enter the Netherlands?

Tags: covid-19

To be specific, I will travel to Amsterdam and I did 3 doze vaccine in France but I will come from Turkey to Amsterdam. Do i need to get PCR test ?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a PCR test when entering the Netherlands, even from outside EU/Schengen.

Dutch government statement: https://www.government.nl/topics/coronavirus-covid-19/visiting-the-netherlands-from-abroad/mandatory-negative-test-results-and-declaration

Comment: Thanks a lot ^^